# Royden Chapter 13 exercise 29 - Linear operators on finite normed linear spaces are continuous and open

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

> Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional normed linear space and $Y$ a normed linear space. Show that every linear operator $T:X \to Y$ is continuous and open.

I am trying to show that this operator is necessarily bounded, however I am not sure why this is true.

Here is what I am thinking

$$\begin{aligned}\|T(x)\|_Y\\
=\|T(c_1e_1 + \dots + c_ne_n)\|_Y\\
<\|c_1T(e_1)+\dots+c_nT(e_n)\|_Y\\
<\|c_1T(e_1)\|_Y+\dots+\|c_nT(e_n)\|_Y\\
<|c_1|\|T(e_1)\|_Y+\dots+|c_n|\|T(e_n)\|_Y\\
\end{aligned}
$$

How can I show that $\|T(x)\|_Y<M\|x\|_X$ for all $x\in X$ if I have no idea what $\|\cdot\|_X$ is?

Answer (score 1):

It should look like the following:
\begin{align*}
\|T(c_1e_1+\cdots+c_ne_n)\|_Y&=\|c_1T(e_1)+\cdots+c_nT(e_n)\|_Y\\
&\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}|c_i|\|T(e_i)\|\\
&\leq M\sum_{i=1}^{n}|c_i|,
\end{align*}
where $M:=\max\{\|T(e_i)\|:1\leq i\leq n\}$. From here it follows by a know results about norms on finite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: Is this becuase all norms are equivalent on finite dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: @SamKirkiles: Yes that is the needed result.

Comment: Thank you this is proved on Chapter 13 page 260 in Royden for future viewers on this question